# How to move a user in a cohort to another without losing their information in Moodle?

Tags: class, content-management-system, moodle

I'm using Moodle version 3.1 for system manage courses and classes in my school. In each class enrolled by 'Cohort Sync' method. When the students what to change class from one to another by keep their information such as grades, id. So this case I have to move them a class of a cohort to other without create new user. How can i do?

Comment: you should attach print screen